# How to ignore function calls throwing a RuntimeExceptions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm supposed to use `tapestry-json` as my JSON-API in Java:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONArray;
```

Unfortunately there is no `optJSONObject(int)`-method for reading `JSONObject`s from a `JSONArray`. The method `getJSONObject(int)` Throws a `RuntimeException`

> ... if there is no value for the index or if the value is not a JSONObject.

Now I'd like to ignore all those entries. Thus I wrapped it in a try-catch-block.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("...");

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject currentEntry;
  try {
    // RuntimeException is thrown, if there is no value for the index or if the value is not a JSONObject.
    currentEntry = arr.getJSONObject(i);
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // Ignore this entry
    continue;
  }
  /*
  if( ... currentEntry ... ) {

  }
  */
}
```

To me, this solution appears heavier that it probably has to be. Is there a more elegant way to ignore RuntimeExceptions?

Comment: You could just get the object and then see if it's a `JSONObject`. Still ugly (using `instanceof`, *ugh...* unless, of course, there is some utility in that library), but at least avoids control flow via exceptions. IMHO the design of this class is not particularly good, it should provide ways to check what the element is.

Comment: Please don't use exception handling as control flow.  It makes the code needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get raw Object from `JSONArray` using `get(int)` method and then test if it is JSONObject. If it is not, then ignore.

Like this:

```
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("...");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        final Object io = arr.get(i);
        if (io instanceof JSONObject){
            // do something
        }
    }
```

btw `getJSONObject(int)` does the same, but throws an exception instead of ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if the Object at index `i` is `instanceof` JSONObject. If so, do what you need to do, if not, ignore it.